# Возвращение массива функцией

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, указатели, динамические-массивы

Есть код. В функции `double f(double x[], int n)` делается вычисление нескольких функций с несколькими переменными. Несколько переменных мы передадим в виде массива `double x[]`, `int n` - количество элементов массива; к примеру, пусть будут вычислятся две функции - я их решил записать в массив `double g[n]`, так как мне надо, что бы функция возвращала оба вычисления функции: `g[0] = x[0] + x[1]; g[1] = x[0] * x[1]`. Как вернуть массив `g[n]`, и каким быть должно обращение к функции (в примере кода сразу в функции `memcpy`)? Что не так, поправьте. 
Пример кода.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double f(double x[], int n) 
{
    double g[n];
    g[0] = x[0] + x[1];
    g[1] = x[0] * x[1];
    return /* Что? */;
}

main() 
{
    int n = 2;
    double a[2], b[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << " a[" << i << "] = ";
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    memcpy(b, f(a, n), sizeof(a));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) cout << " b[" << i << "] = " << b[i];
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Возвращать массив как таковой нельзя. Можно вернуть указатель на него - но тогда массив не должен быть локальной переменной! (Кстати, в C++ нельзя объявлять массив с размером, неизвестным во время компиляции.)

Поэтому нужно иначе..

Выделить массив динамически, и вернуть (только потом не забыть освободить память!)

```
int * g = new int[n];
...
return g;
```

Использовать, скажем, вектор (наилучший вариант):

```
std::vector<int> g(n);
...
return g;
```

Можно обернуть массив в структуру, но опять же, нужно знать размер во время компиляции:

```
struct Array {
    int g[10];
}

...

Array f()
{
    Array g;
    g.g[0] = 5;
    ...
    return g;
}
```

Но лучше всего - использовать готовый вектор, тем более что у вас количество элементов заранее не известно, так что `std::array<>` вам не подойдет.

**PS** Ну и, конечно, вариант с передачей возвращаемого массива в функцию:

```
int g[10];
... f(..., int* g)
{
    // работа с g[i]
    ...
}

...

f(...,g);
```

Comment: можешь на примере моей функции реализовать, используя вектор? И пример вызова функции.

Comment: `vector<double> f(double x[], int n) 
{
    vector<double> g(n);
    g[0] = x[0] + x[1];
    g[1] = x[0] * x[1];
    return g;
}`

Comment: Мои извинения, что ко всему так докапываюсь.. как тогда должны быть объявлены `a[2]` и `b[2]` в главной программе? И каким должен быть вызов функции (к примеру, `b[2]`, или как там он иначе будет объявлен, мы присвоим результат функции, передавая ей `a[2]` и `n`)?..

Comment: будь добр, помоги

Comment: С такими запросами вам [сюда](http://www.reshaem.net/?cGFydG5lcj03OTIy)...